# Stat_summary in GGplot produced wrong results

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

When I run the following code

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = clarity, fill = cut)) +
  geom_bar()
```

It showed the clarity `I1` had different cuts (Fair, Premium, Ideal) as indicated in the output graph

[image]

However, when I used `stat_summary` to show the average price for each cut by clarity, only the value for the `Ideal` cut for the `I1` clarity displayed as shown below (the first bar in the graph).

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=clarity, y=price, fill=cut)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom="bar")
```

[image]

What had happened? What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the bars are being drawn on top of each other; Ideal is the last category drawn, has the highest price, and is obscuring the others.  Try

```r
stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom="bar", position = "stack")
```